# MapsActivity is not loading the map at all

Tags: android, google-maps

I have used the default code to display the map but I wonder why doesn't it works. I have followed the steps showed on Getting Started| Google Maps API. I have generated an API key for the app and have also restricted it.

This is my Code for **MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

double LATITUDE, LONGITUDE;
String MARKER;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Bundle lalo = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (lalo != null){
        LATITUDE = Double.valueOf(lalo.getString("LAT"));
        LONGITUDE = Double.valueOf(lalo.getString("LON"));
        MARKER = lalo.getString("MARKER");
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng location = new LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(MARKER));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
}
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the MapActivity.

[image: Here]

Please help me on this.

Comment: whats your logcat returns ?

Comment: Double check the steps with the API key, you get an empty screen like this if there's a problem with that. Also, is there anything related in the logs?

Comment: did you declare the metadata in manifest 
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBZMlkOv4sj-M5JO9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo" />

Comment: Have you added your correct sha1 key and package name at developer console.

Comment: It is showing Authorization Failure :

Comment: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

Comment: E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                                  Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Comment: Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                                   API Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 33:XX:56:XX:XX:0F:XX:9A:XX:3C:XX:DF:XX:FE:XX:53:XX:83:XX:XX;com.example.www.maptest.app

Answer (score 0):

Are you using release key for debug version which name contains ".debug" ? That will trigger this situation too. You may show the log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it works for me

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapFragment.onResume();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapFragment.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mapFragment.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mapFragment.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        mapFragment.onLowMemory();
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as IntelliJ Amiya told to look for logcat. The logcat was saying Authorization failure which then I solved going to the google maps api console. There I saw my API was correct but the SHA1 key was incorrect so I generated one from the terminal and saved. I did not found any option to enable the Google Maps Android API v2. But I didn't required to enable the Google Maps Android API v2. Else I just placed the correct and newly generated SHA1 key and got it rectified.

Thanks to all for your valuable suggestions.